# SharpGL, проблема с прозрачностью

Tags: c#, opengl, sharpgl

существует фон и картинка с расширениями .bmp, их необходимо поместить на фон.
В картинке часть занимают прозрачные пиксели со значением Alpha в 0, фон же полностью непрозрачен
Вставка обоих картинок проходит нормально, но либо картинка становится полупрозрачна, либо непрозрачна но на чёрном фоне, вместо того, что бы быть на самом фоне(Я надеюсь это более-менее понятно)

```
//Рисование фона
gl.Enable(OpenGL.GL_BLEND);
gl.BlendFunc(OpenGL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, OpenGL.GL_ONE);
//Рисование самой картинки
gl.Disable(OpenGL.GL_BLEND);
```

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что я не могу понять, какие значения необходимо поставить в gl.BlendFunc и нужно но ли вообще использовать её. Я читал статьи на тему этой функции, но, как я понял, данная функция определяет степень прозрачности всей картинки, а мне нужна только прозрачность для пикселей с Alpha равным 0 Картинки и результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Udp:
При использовании параметров GL_SRC_ALPHA ,  GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA
Следующий результат
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`

Comment: @aepot ,к сожалению, это не дало результатов. см пост